# How to make sliding drawer to overlay other elements in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a sliding drawer where handler is a button/text. 
The main reason behind that is to save space. What I hope to achieve is that the drawer would open content op top of the original view. But what actually happens is that the drawer uses a relative space (button+content) in my original view.

I hope picture below will explain it more carefully. So I have a speaker icon in the drawer as a handler. I would like it to take only those 20dp or so space. When I click on the speaker, then the drawer content overlays data below.  When you click on the speaker again, the drawer closes. For now, if I emulate this case, the drawer opens/closes only in the region indicated by blue rectangle.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your screenshot, your sliding drawer is inside of a LinearLayout.

Therefore it cannot do what you are looking for. (As the items in the LinearLayout will be listed linearly - therefore won't overlay)

The documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html says you should only use the Sliding drawer in a Relative or Framelayout (as these allow overlaying):

> SlidingDrawer should be used as an overlay inside layouts. This means
>   SlidingDrawer should only be used inside of a FrameLayout or a
>   RelativeLayout for instance.

I would recommend the following structure:

```
Relative Layout
-Sliding Drawer (id: slidingDrawer, aligned to parent top)
-Linear Layout (id: contentLyout, aligned as below id:slidingDrawer)
--TextView (id: deviceTitle)
--ScrollView (id: contentScroll)
---LinearLayout (I can't see the rest of your layout)
```

Comment: My apologies for not being careful. Thank you you.

Comment: I added a recommended layout for how I think I would do it. the linearlayout is not entirel necessary (you could set the textview below the sliding drawer, then set the scrollview below that) but this way fits more with what you are currently doing